# Plot decision tree splitting in a plane

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree, visualization

I am fitting a regression tree with 2 variables with `sklearn`. I'd like to visualize how the tree splits the plane. I am thinking this very plane with tiles corresponding to leaves and their color corresponding to the average values of the dependent variable within the leaves. Is there any existing library to do this? Otherwise, any idea how I easily draw tiles with e.g. `matplotlib`?

Comment: `R` has unravelled capabilities of plotting decision trees. Note, a single decision tree has high variability and most likely will change depending on subsample of your data. With many trees (think random forest), the variability is decreased, but on the other hand the value of graphically analyzing thousands of trees decreasing as well.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thank you but I don't see how that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris_dtc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-iris-dtc-py) example to build what you need.

Try this example:

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,n_features=2, 
n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=4)
labels = ['type_A', 'type_B']
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3).fit(X, y)

# Parameters
n_classes = 2
plot_colors = "ryb"
plot_step = 0.02

# Plot the decision boundary
plt.figure()

x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, plot_step),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, plot_step))
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, pad=2.5)

Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)

plt.xlabel('feature_1')
plt.ylabel('feature_2')

# Plot the training points
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), plot_colors):
    idx = np.where(y == i)
    plt.scatter(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], c=color, label=labels,
                cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu, edgecolor='black', s=15)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
plot_tree(clf, filled=True, feature_names=['feature_1', 'feature_2'],
          ax=ax, fontsize=6,
          class_names=labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

For regression problem,

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np


X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=2,n_informative=2,
                       random_state=0)
reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4).fit(X, y)

# Parameters
plot_colors = "ryb"
plot_step = 0.02

# Plot the decision boundary
f, axes =plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(30, 7))

x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, plot_step),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, plot_step))
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, pad=2.5)

Z = reg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

plt.xlabel('feature_1')
plt.ylabel('feature_2')

axes[1].scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y,
            cmap='Oranges', edgecolor='black', s=15)

plot_tree(reg, filled=True, feature_names=['feature_1', 'feature_2'],
          ax=axes[0], fontsize=3,
          class_names='Target')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks more like what I need though in my case it's a regression tree (I have added the precision in the question). I believe `plt.contour` and `np.meshgrid` will help me a great deal. I'll look into all this. Thanks !

Comment: Glad that it helped. I have added a regression example now. Check it out. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Perfectly ! Thanks !

Comment: @Venkatachalam in my case i'm using the playtenis dataset, my x has several attributes that decide whether y will play tennis or not, as x has several attributes how can i visualize this? in this case you used 2 features

Comment: Use t-sne to reduce the dimensionality.